# How to send data to client-side if there is new data using AngularJS in Struts 2

Tags: angularjs, struts2, streaming

I have the following problem: I'm using Struts 2 with AngularJS. Requesting data from Action Classes is no Problem. But what if I want to continuously stream data (JSONs) to the client-side?

So if there is new data available in the backend, it should be send to the frontend and automatically displayed there.

Any hint how to do that?

Comment: You may wanna look at socket.io

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use servlet API 3.0 or higher for the web application that allows to use websocket on the server-side. There you can define your endpoints that allow you  *continuously stream data (JSONs) to the client-side*.

One point that Struts2 should be excluded from the service because it interfere with the API and doesn't support websockets.